# JRockit HSPerf data documentation

Tags: jrockit

Is there some documentation for JRockit hsperf data metrics? What all the parameters mean, how time measures are represented (equivalent of HotSpot's `sun.os.hrt.frequency`), ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JRockit help for `jrcmd` states that

> counters are for internal use by Oracle and are not officially supported or documented

However, I found this blog post, that summarizes at least part of the counters. Not exhaustive, but useful indeed. https://blogs.oracle.com/hirt/entry/the_jrockit_performance_counte